# Sheet DataFrame turns to not equal with same constructed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need help with this as I have search for solutions for almost 3 hours already but had not found anything.

I have here a simple `pandas` dataframe created from the script and this dataframe gets uploaded to a google sheet with the use of the [Google Sheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python).

**Source code:**

```
import gspread, pandas as pd

cols = [
"Filename",
"Version Number",
"House Name",
]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

for i in range(0,5):
    out = {
    "Filename":i,
    "Version Number":i+1,
    "House Name":i+2
    }
    df = df.append(out,ignore_index=True)





creds_path = "creds.json"
service_account = gspread.service_account(filename=creds_path)
spreadsheet = service_account.open_by_key("1a8NxVF6yUE0jSa63tjhEDHAS2q7dsdo0lT4saMGKROI")
worksheet = spreadsheet.sheet1


df2 = pd.DataFrame(worksheet.get_all_records())
print(df.equals(df2))

#worksheet.clear()
#worksheet.update([df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist())
```

This is a very simple script, it creates a `pandas` dataframe then uploads it to the google sheet **programmatically**. I made this sheet for **testing purposes** which I can publicly give it to anyone and also if you would like to try it out you will need the `.json` file which contains the credentials, which also I have made one for anyone if would like to try it but take note that this is **for testing purposes only**.

> Note: I will be deactivating credentials once the question is
> answered.

Links:

- [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a8NxVF6yUE0jSa63tjhEDHAS2q7dsdo0lT4saMGKROI/edit?usp=sharing)
- [creds.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13CVtF8_6j_Ns43dvcDBYvuu6t5ynzT9J/view?usp=sharing)

Now here's the issue I am having. Once the `pandas` dataframe is created then upload it with this part of code. `worksheet.clear()` & `worksheet.update([df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist())`. You can clearly see on the sheet that it works and the sheet looks like this.

[image: sheet image]

Now when I try to **READ** the sheet and convert it to a `pandas` dataframe with this.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(worksheet.get_all_records())
```

I just wanted too **see** if the data on the sheet is **EXACTLY THE SAME** as the dataframe created on the script. Now when I run this `print(df.equals(df2))` it returns `False` meaning the `df` is not the same `dataframe` as `df2` which is I can see clearly **NOT WHAT I EXPECTED**. Cause clearly I uploaded the same dataframe but why is it saying `False` when you compare the two? Where in fact it should be `True` right?

If you try to print out `df` & `df2` you can see it clearly that they are the same right? I suggest you try to print it out from the script by yourself.

**df**:

```
  Filename Version Number House Name
0        0              1          2
1        1              2          3
2        2              3          4
3        3              4          5
4        4              5          6
```

****df2**:**

```
   Filename  Version Number  House Name
0         0               1           2
1         1               2           3
2         2               3           4
3         3               4           5
4         4               5           6
```

**Main Objective:**

> My objective is just to **see** if the data from the sheet is
> **exactly the same** as the created dataframe in the script. I just wanted to like to check if they are the same cause I would be doing
> other stuffs depending on that condition.

Can someone educate me for whatever I am missing here. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I'd like to keep the sheet and creds so that if someone encounters this issue they could try it and it might help them solve their problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gspread API returned a dataframe `df2` with type `int64` while the dataframe `df` that you created manually has type `int`. Since the types are different, the two dataframes are not equal.

If you try `df.astype('int64').equals(df2)` it will return `True`.

Alternatively you can use `all(df.eq(df2))`, which will also return `True`. This compares each element of the dataframe, and the Boolean flags are combined using `all`.

A third way (suggested by the OP in the comments below) is to do `df.astype("str").equals(df2.astype("str"))`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Unfortunately... my values for every column could be anything like `int` `float` `strings` anything... I think I forgot about that. So for this situation the `df.astype('int64').equals(df2)` is pretty good and it'll not be a solution for an example where a column value would be like a word right? So just wondering if the `all(df.eq(df2))` would be able to cover that too?

Comment: as long as you're comparing the same dtype, df.eq(df2) should work, but if you compare, say, `'1'` with `1`, then it won't

Comment: cool! I have tried with another sample dataframe but unfortunately the provided solutions did not work but I have thought of something base on your answers that inspired me. I tried to do a `df.astype("str").equals(df2.astype("str"))` and works fine.. May I ask if this solution I've thought of would be like okay? or is it not  good in terms of time complexity? Thanks! I think this solves my issue. Is it okay if you could add it on your answer as another solution. Without your answer I would not have thought of this.

Comment: Now I have in mind that the type of those data in the dataframe are a big deal when in terms of comparing two dataframes.

Comment: @IceBear I've added your solution into my answer as well :) it looks fine to me and I don't think it will cause performance issues. casting to string is not an expensive process.

Comment: Great! Still I'm accepting other answers even tho I have accepted an answer cause people do that still here right but this answers the question for me and also your answers I think I actually might need them in my next tasks. Thanks!!